# ¿Como imprimir multiples paginas con PrintDocument en C# utilizando un ciclo?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Aquí lo que he intentado:

```
 private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {             
                string reporte = "";
                if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
                {
                    reporte = "Por Codigo";
                }
                if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
                {
                    reporte = "Por Factura";
                }
                if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
                {
                    reporte = "Por Proveedor";
                }
                int contador = 0;
                double total = 0;

                ///// Se establece el tipo de Fuente        
                Font Fuente = new Font("Verdana", 8);
                Font FuenteEncabezados = new Font("Verdana", 10);
                Font FuenteF = new Font("Verdana", 8);

                //titulo
                Font fuente_titulo = new Font("Verdana", 16, FontStyle.Bold);

                ///// Se establece el Color de Fuente
                Brush Brocha = Brushes.Black;
                ///// Se establece las cordenadas
                int Y = 35;

                //se genera el cuadro de la fecha y #cotizacion
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 650, 45, 174, 40);



                e.Graphics.DrawString(Program.GGG.empresa, fuente_titulo, Brocha, 190, 20);
                Y = Convert.ToInt32(Y + Fuente.GetHeight());
                //muestra el logo
                Bitmap logo = Sistema.Properties.Resources.logo;
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(logo, 20, 20, 150, 100);

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Reporte de Compras", fuente_titulo, Brocha, (e.MarginBounds.Width /2), 115);

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Tel: " + Program.GGG.telefono_empresa, Fuente, Brocha, 190, 45);
                Y = Convert.ToInt32(Y + Fuente.GetHeight());

                e.Graphics.DrawString("RTN: " + Program.GGG.RTN, Fuente, Brocha, 190, 65);
                Y = Convert.ToInt32(Y + Fuente.GetHeight());

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Direccion: " + Program.GGG.direccion, Fuente, Brocha, 190, 85);
                Y = Convert.ToInt32(Y + Fuente.GetHeight());

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Fecha" , FuenteEncabezados, Brocha, 20, 146);
                Y = Convert.ToInt32(Y + Fuente.GetHeight());

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Codigo", FuenteEncabezados, Brocha, 130, 146);
                Y = Convert.ToInt32(Y + Fuente.GetHeight());

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Descripcion", FuenteEncabezados, Brocha, 200, 146);
                Y = Convert.ToInt32(Y + Fuente.GetHeight());

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Cantidad", FuenteEncabezados, Brocha, 550, 146);
                Y = Convert.ToInt32(Y + Fuente.GetHeight());

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Precio", FuenteEncabezados, Brocha, 650, 146);
                Y = Convert.ToInt32(Y + Fuente.GetHeight());

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Total", FuenteEncabezados, Brocha, 750, 146);
                Y = Convert.ToInt32(Y + Fuente.GetHeight());

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Reporte:     " + reporte, Fuente, Brocha, 650, 45);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Fecha:" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), FuenteF, Brocha, 650, 65);

                //se genera el cuadro de los articulos
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)

                {
                    if (row.Cells[1].Value != DBNull.Value || row.Cells[2].Value != DBNull.Value || row.Cells[3].Value != DBNull.Value || row.Cells[4].Value != DBNull.Value || row.Cells[5].Value != DBNull.Value) {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[0].Value).ToShortDateString(), Fuente, Brocha, 23, Y);
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), Fuente, Brocha, 130, Y);
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), Fuente, Brocha, 200, Y);
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString(), Fuente, Brocha, 550, Y);
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), Fuente, Brocha, 650, Y);
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(row.Cells[5].Value.ToString(), Fuente, Brocha, 750, Y);
                    }


                    Y = Y + 20;
                    contador++;

                    if (Y >= 500)
                    {
                        e.HasMorePages = true;
                        Y = 30;
                        return;
                    }else
                    {
                        e.HasMorePages = false;
                    }
                }


                //se genera el cuadro de los articulos
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 20, 145, 825, 145);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 20, 165, 825, 165);

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 20, 145, 20, Y);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 825, 145, 825, Y);


                //se genera el cuadro de los totales
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 20, Y, 805, 25);

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Total: " + suma.ToString("N2"), Fuente, Brocha, 640, Y+2);
                Y = Convert.ToInt32(Y + Fuente.GetHeight());
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

La idea es imprimir un datagridview con información, este datagrid lo recorro con un ForEach, Pero cuando se ejecuta entra en un ciclo de nunca acbar. Siempre sigue imprimiendo. No logro hacer que cuando dispare el e.HasMorePages = true siga a otra pagina. Encontre [esta pregunta en SO en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561611/multiple-page-print-document-in-c-sharp) pero no puedo adapatarla a mi codigo. Si hay que cambiar algo lo podemos hacer.

Espero su ayuda. Atento a cualquier consulta.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando se ejecuta este proceso, empieza de cero de vuelta? no deberias tener un metodo que sepa donde dejaste de recorrer la grilla, y continuar desde ahi?

Comment: Si, pero como podría controlar eso?

Comment: y.. tener mas variables de control? mantener una clase con el estado?

Comment: El problema es que no se como controlar ese Foreach para que se rompa

Comment: tal vez necesites una clase y un for controlado con un yield?

Comment: Podrias darme un ejemplo?